# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI

Tags: android-studio, xml, flutter, dart, android-manifest

tengo un problema al momento de ejecutar mi app en flutter a mi emulador con Android 12 o posterior, actualmente estoy trabajando con Flutter 1.22.2, ya que la app estaba desarrollada con esa versión y sólo me quedó continuarla.
El problema que tengo es que al momento de ejecutar la app me sale este error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
adb: failed to install /Volumes/Pedidos Online Disk/AndroidStudioProjects/carpeta sin título/customer-app-pedidos-online/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1367390883.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #305): io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
```

Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64.

Ya modifiqué mi AndroidManifest como indican en diferentes foros y en la documentación de Android pero sigue sin funcionar.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pedidosonline.pedidos_online_cliente">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="Pedidos Online"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled"
        android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoInitEnabled"
        android:value="false"/>
    
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- If utilizing $deeplink_path please explicitly declare your hosts, or utilize a wildcard(*) -->
            <data android:scheme="pedidosonline" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Branch App Links -->
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="link.pedidosonline.com" />
            <!-- example-alternate domain is required for App Links when the Journeys/Web SDK and Deepviews are used inside your website.  -->
           <!-- <data android:scheme="https" android:host="bwtq2-alternate.app.link" />-->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="pedidosonline-alternate.app.link" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="bwtq2.test-app.link"/>
            <!-- example-alternate domain is required for App Links when the Journeys/Web SDK and Deepviews are used inside your website.  -->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="bwtq2-alternate.test-app.link" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="pedidosonline.app.link" />
            <!-- example-alternate domain is required for App Links when the Journeys/Web SDK and Deepviews are used inside your website.  -->
            <!-- <data android:scheme="https" android:host="bwtq2-alternate.app.link" />-->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="pedidosonline-alternate.app.link" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="bwtq2.app.link" />
            <!-- example-alternate domain is required for App Links when the Journeys/Web SDK and Deepviews are used inside your website.  -->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="bwtq2-alternate.app.link" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Deep Linking -->
        <!-- Deep linking -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="app.pedidosonline.com"
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:exported="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!--<data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />-->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="apikey"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
   
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
    <!-- Branch init -->
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_branch" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="key_test_branch" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />     <!-- Set to true to use Branch_Test_Key (useful when simulating installs and/or switching between debug and production flavors) -->


</application>
```

Ese es mi AndroidManifest donde agregué android:exported="true", pero sigue sin funcionar, alguien que sepa como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Puedes poner el error como un fragmento de código? No todos podemos ver las imágenes

Comment: Acabo de modificar la pregunta, no tomé en cuenta ese detalle, gracias por aclararlo